# Are there any Servinenow community here that I might join ?

Tags: servicenow

Any tip or direction to join some Servicenow community? I am trying to build NPS report and I am a bit stuck.

Comment: You might check ServiceNow's community at https://community.servicenow.com, they may be able to help.

Comment: You could also make a post here about your issue with the report.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few places;

- https://community.servicenow.com (official community) they have
  service now user groups as well probably in your local area
- https://invite.sndevs.com (unofficial slack community)
- https://www.meetup.com/pro/servicenowdevprogram/ (official meetup
  developer community)
- https://reddit.com/r/servicenow (kinda low
  quantity of content here but its a place)

Comment: If you know of more please share them as well.

Comment: sure, I will if I find more